# TextMate: Indent settings for JavaScript in <script> tags

Tags: textmate, indentation

Our style guide wants JavaScript to be indented by 4 spaces and HTML by 2.

I've got custom settings for `.js` and `.html` files. However, when I edit JavaScript inside `<script>` tags in HTML, TextMate indents the JavaScript by 2 spaces instead of 4.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to create indentation rules in TextMate bundles, but from what I've read, I do not believe it's possible to dynamically change the auto-indentation based on the type of indentation tag. The indentation rules documentation can be found in [section 24 of the TextMate manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/appendix#indentation_rules.html).

What you could do is add a command to the HTML bundle that has a regex that looks for <script> tags and then properly re-indents the lines preceeding the next </script> tag. You could then run this to automatically fix the indentation. See [Commands](http://manual.macromates.com/en/commands) in the TextMate manual.

Hope this helps a bit...